# While using streams, why is it echoing the previous output?

Tags: java, flush

I was trying to buffer the content in a file using BufferedReader. In the process, i gave a wrong constraint in the below program `while((line = in.readLine()) != "\n")`, which gives me an undesired output.

I later corrected it, as `while((line = in.readLine()) != "null")`, which should be able to display the content in the file (new file), but it is continuing to show the same wrong output again.

```
import java.io.*;

    public class ReaderTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/a1340/new file"));

                    String line="";
                    while((line = in.readLine()) != "\n"){
                    System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    in.close();

                  }
                }

        import java.io.*;

        public class ReaderTest {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/a1340/new file"));

                        String line="";
                        while((line = in.readLine()) != "null"){
                        System.out.println(line);
                        }
                        in.close();

                      }
                    }
```

Comment: remove the double quotes around `null`

Comment: oh yea .. no quotes.. the problem persists yet. I think the buffer needs to be flushed. ?? But am confused how to??

Comment: no need of flushing mate. I use this all the time. May be, problem is with `FileReader`, try `FileInputStream` instead. Below is my answer, try it

Answer (score 5):

[`readLine()` returns null](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) when it reaches the end of the stream, so you need to compare to `null`, not `"null"`:

```
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
```

Comment: sry.. i meant null not "null"..  @Binyamin Sharet

Comment: try clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

Use null without quotes

```
while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`null` is not a `String` type in java

You need to use `null` as it is

```
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
     System.out.println(line);
}
```

Using `FileInputStream`

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileInputStream(new File("filename")));

while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as others have said, you need to compare to `null`.

But also, you should use `.equals(...)` to compare `String` objects, not the inequality operator `!=`.

I.e. write this

```
if ("\n".equals(line)) { ... }
```

not this:

```
if ("\n" == line) { ... }
```

Also, the java platform knows the native line termination sequence for the underlying OS Via `System.getProperty("line.separator");`

Some platforms use `\r\n`

Lastly, I'm proposing `"literal".equals(variable)` instead of `variable.equals("literal")` because the first for will work if `variable` is `null`.